# Weak solution of boundary problem with fundamental lemma of calculus

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I have following boundary value problem:

$-(au')'=0$ in $\Omega=(0,1)$

$u(0)=1$

$u(1)=0$

with 
\begin{equation}
   a(x) =
   \begin{cases}
     \kappa \alpha &  x \in (0,\epsilon) \\
     \alpha & x\in (\epsilon,1)
   \end{cases}
\end{equation}

and $\kappa , \alpha >0$

I wanna find the weak solution $u\in H^1(0,1)$ and show uniqueness. Also im interested if this is a classical solution.

My idea is to determine a weak formulation of the problem and then maybe use following  fundamental lemma of calculus of variations:

If $\omega \in L^2((a,b))$ satisfies 
$$\int ^b_a \omega v'=0 $$
for all $v\in C^{\infty}_0 ((a,b))$
then $\omega$ is constant on $(a,b)$

Unfortunately im totally stuck. Anyone can help and know how to handle it?

Comment: When you write $f(x)$ do you mean $a(x)$?

Comment: @Ian yes, indeed.  Thanks for correction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by multiplying by a test function $v$ and integrating by parts. This initially reads

$$-\int_0^1 (au')' v dx = 0.$$

Integrating by parts gives

$$\left. -(au')v \right |_{0}^1 + \int_0^1 au' v' dx = 0.$$

By choosing test functions with homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions, the boundary terms vanish, giving

$$\int_0^1 au'v' dx = 0 \quad \\
u(0)=1,u(1)=0.$$

This choice is necessary, without it the problem does not have a solution (because the test functions that vanish on the boundary already determine $u$ uniquely).

This means $au'$ is constant almost everywhere, which means $u$ is piecewise linear, with the break being at $x=\epsilon$. The boundary conditions plus continuity (which is automatic from the assumption $u \in H^1$, by Sobolev embedding considerations) gives you three equations for the four unknown coefficients. How can you get a fourth equation? (Hint: it is a relationship between the slopes.)

Comment: Mhh thanks a lot so far but can you please show me how you get the weak formulation? Im stuck there so cant follow up

Comment: @SquareJoe Does it make sense now?

Comment: It does. Probably missing something easy but where did the ' go? its $(au')'$ and not $(au')$

Comment: @SquareJoe Typo. (It goes away after the very first step, so I forgot about it.)

Comment: I gave it a shot but i cant find the fourth equation. Can you specify?

Comment: @SquareJoe $au'$ is constant, so you get a relationship between the slope for $x<\epsilon$ and the slope for $x>\epsilon$. You don't directly get either one of them from just this relationship, but you can use the other three equations together with this one to piece together everything you need.